# Ckeditor Arabic characters not appear right

Tags: html

I have a problem when I write Arabic language in Ck editor ( ّ  ) character appear �'

إذا أم�'ت أي�'ة سفينة إحدى المرافئ
اذا أمّت أيّة سفينة احدى المرافئ

Answer (score 0):

you should change encoding in your editor to UTF-8

Comment: add accept-charset="UTF-8"  and <script type="text/javascript" src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js" charset="utf-8"></script>